# Hadoop's Capacity Scheduler - Setting up multiple queues

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I tried to set up 2 queues - queue1,queue2.
I added the names of these queues to the mapred-site.xml

```
    <property>
        <name>mapred.queue.names</name>
        <value>queue1,queue2</value>
    </property>
```

I configured CapacityScheduler.xml as shown below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.maximum-system-jobs</name>
            <value>3000</value>   
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.capacity</name>
            <value>100</value>   
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.capacity</name>
            <value>100</value>   
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.maximum-capacity</name>
            <value>-1</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.maximum-capacity</name>
            <value>-1</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.supports-priority</name>
            <value>false</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.supports-priority</name>
            <value>false</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.minimum-user-limit-percent</name>
            <value>100</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.minimum-user-limit-percent</name>
            <value>100</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.user-limit-factor</name>
            <value>1</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.user-limit-factor</name>
            <value>1</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.maximum-initialized-active-tasks</name>
            <value>200000</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.maximum-initialized-active-tasks</name>
            <value>200000</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.maximum-initialized-active-tasks-per-user</name>
            <value>100000</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.maximum-initialized-active-tasks-per-user</name>
            <value>100000</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.init-accept-jobs-factor</name>
            <value>10</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.init-accept-jobs-factor</name>
            <value>10</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.default-supports-priority</name>
            <value>false</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.default-minimum-user-limit-percent</name>
            <value>100</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.default-user-limit-factor</name>
            <value>1</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.default-maximum-active-tasks-per-queue</name>
            <value>200000</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.default-maximum-active-tasks-per-user</name>
            <value>100000</value>
         </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.default-init-accept-jobs-factor</name>
            <value>10</value>
         </property>

         <!-- Capacity scheduler Job Initialization configuration parameters -->
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.init-poll-interval</name>
            <value>5000</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.init-worker-threads</name>
            <value>5</value>
         </property>
    </configuration>
```

The bin/start-all.sh starts the following services.

```
    17083 DataNode
    17557 TaskTracker
    17373 JobTracker
    16902 NameNode
    17279 SecondaryNameNode
    17703 Jps
```

Im able to view the WEB UI for Jobtracker in

```
    http://localhost:50030/
```

Tasktracker's WEB UI

```
    http://localhost:50060/
```

shows "Unable to Connect". But after a few seconds the jobtracker and tasktracker shuts down. jps command on the terminal only shows

```
    17083 DataNode
    16902 NameNode
    17279 SecondaryNameNode
    17703 Jps
```

What might be the solution.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue, did find any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

both of your queues have a capacity of 100 , which makes the capacity scheduler to think there are couple of queues that each have a capacity of 100%. I suggest you change the setting to :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
     <property>
        <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.maximum-system-jobs</name>
        <value>3000</value>   
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.capacity</name>
        <value>80</value> <!-- change here -->
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.capacity</name>
        <value>20</value> <!-- change here -->   
     </property>

     <property>
        <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue1.maximum-capacity</name>
        <value>-1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>mapred.capacity-scheduler.queue.queue2.maximum-capacity</name>
        <value>-1</value>
     </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all your queues must always and only be 100 (ie 100%) you can have two queues with 100 and 0 percent respectively - that is valid.

Also I think it's good practice to always have a "default" queue, with some allocation at the very least. I don't know what the scheduler will do if you don't specify the queue name when you don't have a default.